# felixge MYSQL module delay?

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket

I'm using a node.js + websocket + https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql.

I have a small script here:

```
sql.query('SELECT hash FROM dateinfo ORDER BY date LIMIT 1',function(error,erows){
    if(error) throw err;
    var oldhash,oldrolls;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        oldhash = rows[i].hash;
        oldrolls = rows[i].rolls;
     };
     console.log(oldhash);
 });
```

After successful query, console prints "undefined". But if I print that variable after some time (let's say 1s), it will print "test" (as the mysql field contains "test").
I heard that this is the problem with node.js async...

I'm stuck here, what should I do?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the logic of that code I think you have an extra `}`

Comment: ahh my bad, but that is not the cause

Comment: Also setting a scalar variable in a loop will only show you the last `rows` content

Comment: `rows` is actually undefined since your second parameter is called `erows`

Comment: @Cludch I did not see that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rows` is actually undefined since your second parameter is called `erows`